# Getting error by using Queue[] queues = new Queue[10];

Tags: java, queue

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import unit4.collectionsLib.*;

public class Page255Project_class
{
    static Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void radixSort(int[] numbers){
        Queue[] queues = new Queue[10];
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
            if(numbers[i]%10 == i)
            {
                queues[i].insert(numbers[i]);
                System.out.println(queues[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[10];

        numbers[0] = 170;
        numbers[1] = 45;
        numbers[2] = 75;
        numbers[3] = 90;
        numbers[4] = 2;
        numbers[5] = 24;
        numbers[6] = 802;

        radixSort(numbers);
    }
}
```

And I’m getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Page255Project_class.radixSort(Page255Project_class.java:15)
    at Page255Project_class.main(Page255Project_class.java:33)
```

Please help to solve that error

Comment: You are missing something like `queues[i] = new Queue();` before you can call `queues[i].insert()`...

Comment: You haven't initialized any of the elements in your `Queue[]`.

Comment: Remember that the default value for an Object is null.

Comment: if the dufault value is null, the function "insert" still in to insert to the array the value.. isn't it true?

Comment: No, you're trying to call the insert method on the object in the array, and since the object in the array is `null`, that results in an NPE. Edit: Also, I don't think the boolean check you do is what you want, as it is now, only 170 would end up in your Queue array.

Comment: you are right, only 170 is displaying.
So what a I suppost to do ?

Answer (score 2):

In your function radixSort you have defined array of size 10 holds 10 "empty slots", but you forgot to initialize all of the slots.

The change in your code will be like the following:

```
public static void radixSort(int[] numbers) {
    Queue[] queues = new Queue[10];
    Arrays.fill(queues, new Queue()); // Queue is interface you need to implement it 
                                      // or you need to choose specific type of
                                      // queues [PriorityQueue, LinkedBlockingQueue, ...]
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if(numbers[i] % 10 == i) {
            queues[i].insert(numbers[i]);
            System.out.println(queues[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't do what you did, cause that way is not the way that i'm learning in school

BUT, I tried what assylias suggest me to do:

`public static void radixSort(int[] numbers){

  Queue[] queues = new Queue[10];

  for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){

   if(numbers[i]%10 == i)

   {

    queues[i] = new Queue();

    queues[i].insert(numbers[i]);

    System.out.println(queues[i]);

   }

  }

 }`